# Listen to blur event on a whole FormGroup in a reactive form

Tags: angular

I am creating a large form, and I want to fire a notification and save data, each time the user exits a field (on blur). The problem is that I cannot find an observable for that event for the whole FormGroup. I now listen for value change, but that of course emits all the time. Example:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.saveFormData();
    this.emitSaveNotification();
});
```

Controllers does not have any way of listening to blur neither, so I cannot loop `this.myForm.controls` to add a subscription to the blur event.

Do I have to add a event listener to each element individually?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A solution could be to add on the form the option {updateOn: 'blur'}

```
<form [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

That will make that the value change will be triggered only when the user blur an input, not on every change, using this with your code should work

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
     this.saveFormData();
     this.emitSaveNotification();
});
```

**Edit 1**
You can also add the updateOn option on the FormGroup creation if you are using model driven form:

```
this.nameForm = new FormGroup ({
    onecontrol: new FormControl('', ),
    othercontrol: new FormControl('', )
}, { updateOn: 'blur' });
```

Comment: That works for now. Hopefully I won't need to observe value changes or submits =)

Comment: I am glad that works! It's great not needing to observe that kind of things :)

Comment: Most of us will still need to trigger change detection on submit and valueChanges, so that solution only helps a narrow use case.

Comment: I checked the docs but didn't see anything around listening for multiple events. I tried `{updateOn: ['blur', 'change']}` and {updateOn: 'blur change'}, with no luck. Seems strange for the angular team to miss something so obvious, they usually do a great job of covering use cases.